# Syntax error: operator expected when trying to compare

Tags: prolog

I am trying to compare S1 with A1, S2 with A2, ..., S5 with A5 and get the total number of pairs that match each other. But the interpreter shows "syntax error, operator expected". Is there any simple approach to solve this problem and what's wrong with my code? Thanks!

```
grade(S1, S2, S3, S4, S5, A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, N):-
   S1 = A1, grade2(S2, S3, S4, S5, A2, A3, A4, A5, N+1).

grade(S1, S2, S3, S4, S5, A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, N):-
   \+ S1=A1, grade2(S2, S3, S4, S5, A2, A3, A4, A5, N).

grade2(S2, S3, S4, S5, A2, A3, A4, A5, N):-
   S2=A2, grade3(S3, S4, S5, A3, A4, A5, N+1).

grade2(S2, S3, S4, S5, A2, A3, A4, A5, N):-
   \+ S2=A2, grade3(S3, S4, S5, A3, A4, A5, N).

grade3(S3, S4, S5, A3, A4, A5, N):-
   S3=A3, grade4(S4, S5, A4, A5, N+1).

grade3(S3, S4, S5, A3, A4, A5, N):-
   \+ S3=A3, grade4(S4, S5, A4, A5, N).

grade4(S4, S5, A4, A5, N):-
   S4=A4, grade5(S5, A5, N+1).

grade4(S4, S5, A4, A5, N):-
   \+ S4=A4, grade5(S5, A5, N).

grade5(S5, A5, N):-
   S5=A5, N is 1. 

grade5(S5, A5, N):-
   \+ S5=A5, N is 0.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get any syntax error from your code, but it can't execute: your first rule (for instance) should read

```
grade(S1, S2, S3, S4, S5, A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, N):-
  S1 = A1, grade2(S2, S3, S4, S5, A2, A3, A4, A5, M),
  N is M+1.
```

You used is/2 in the only place where it's useless. Last rule(s) *could* read

```
grade5(S5, S5, 1):-!.
grade5(_, _, 0).
```

Then for some easier to read code (understanding code with too much useless detail is harmful for my poor brain...), using library(aggregate)

```
grade(S1, S2, S3, S4, S5, A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, N):-
  aggregate_all(count,
    (nth1(I,[S1,S2,S3,S4,S5],X),
     nth1(I,[A1,A2,A3,A4,A5],X)
    ), N).
```

I get

```
4 ?- grade(a,b,c,d,e, u,v,c,d,x, N).
N = 2.
```

Answer (score 1):

With SWI-Prolog and module lambda you can write :

```
:- use_module(library(lambda)).

grade(S1, S2, S3, S4, S5, A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, N) :-
    foldl(\X^Y^Z^T^(X = Y ->  T is Z+1 ;   T = Z),
         [S1, S2, S3, S4, S5],
         [A1, A2, A3, A4, A5],
         0, N).
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce your error. However, as it is now it cannot work because of the way you calculate the value of N. If you do a trace you should be able to see where it goes wrong.

Anyway, although you seem to know in advance how many pairs you are comparing, a more generic approach is to put the pairs in two lists, or even better, in a list of pairs:

```
[S1-A1, S2-A2, ...]
```

The `-` here is just a way of writing `-(S, A)`, and the usual Prolog way of representing "pairs". Once the list of pairs is in this form, you could then explicitly write:

```
grade([], 0).
grade([S-A|Rest], N) :-
    (   S == A
    ->  Add = 1
    ;   Add = 0
    ),
    grade(Rest, N0),
    N is N0 + Add.
```

Note that you cannot use tail-recursion unless you have an extra argument to collect the result so far:

```
grade([], N, N).
grade([S-A|Rest], Acc, N) :-
    (   S == A
    ->  NewAcc is Acc + 1
    ;   NewAcc = Acc
    ),
    grade(Rest, NewAcc, N).
```

(you need to "initialize" the accumulator when you call the predicate)

```
?- grade(List, 0, N).
```

So for your case:

- use your initial approach, but fix how N is calculated taking either of the two approaches shown
- represent your list of pairs as an actual list of pairs
- if you are working with lists, there are other techniques available, see library(aggregate), for example. Might be useful for more complex problems of the same kind.

Comment: You can also use tail recursion if you use your system's finite domain constraints (you do not need an extra argument). If you write `N #= N0 + Add`, then you can freely move the goal before the recursive call. If the grades are integers, you can also use constraint reification like `S #= A #<==> Add` instead of the non-declarative usage of if/then/else. This lets you use the predicate in all directions.